# A specific example regarding the inscribed square problem

Tags: geometry

Toeplitz' conjecture (also called inscribed square problem) says that:

> For every Jordan curve $\mathscr C$, there exists four distincts points $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ belonging to $\mathscr C$ such that $ABCD$ is a square.

*A Jordan curve is a non self-intersecting continuous loop.*

Here is a drawing to illustrate the situation, and a link to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem) if you want to find out more about this conjecture.

[image]

The conjecture has already been proven in several cases, including when $\mathscr C$ is piecewise analytic.

So we know that for these two figures, there exists an inscribed square.

[image]
[image]

> **The question** is how do I find those squares?

[image]

Comment: Could you describe more explicitly your two polygons?

Comment: @Aretino Not exactly... I was trying to convince myself that Toeplitz' conjecture is indeed true, so I tried it on a few example, but I did not manage to find a square in those particular ones.

Comment: Are you looking for a general algorithm to find a square in any regular curve?

Comment: @Aretino I don't dare to hope that such algorithm would exist (does it?), I was just wondering about that particular example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is. If we draw an orthogonal line with respect to the one that is aligned with the curve, then you can build the square. [image]